# SharePoint list losing JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

In SharePoint Online I add simple JSON sectioning to a list form. Preview looks fine and saving the JSON works, too.

But after closing the dialog and opening a list item, the formatting is lost.

Going back into the JSON dialog, it is empty.

The list has about 70 fields, but even with a simple JSON the error persists.

```
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "Header",
            "fields": [
                "Title",
                "Description",
                "Introduction",
                "Priority"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This are two screenshots: first the form after successfully adding the JSON and below after hitting CTRL+R.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like lot of people facing the same issue recently. Follow this thread: [SharePoint List Form Configure Layout - Body Not Working](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-list-form-configure-layout-body-not-working/m-p/2596475). Is this a new list, recently created using "create from an existing list" feature?

Answer (score 1):

**In general**, I would suggest after reviewing the JSON format code to make a copy of your formula and then paste it into any editor to allow rollback in case you get such unexpected behavior.

**Regarding this unexpected behavior**, there may be a problem with your browser cache, so try

- Clear browser cache
- Use Microsoft Edge in a private session and check if you get your formula back!

**Finally,** I would like to suggest

- Create a new list from scratch and check if you can apply your format code or not!
- If the problem persists, try opening a ticket with Microsoft Support, it could be a temporary problem!

Comment: I was trying the private session.
As before JSON gets saved, form displayed correctly immediately. Upon refreshing, the JSON is lost.
Contacted MS.

Answer (score 1):

"I have solved this by turning off the sync for the list in List Settings > Advanced Settings > Set Offline client availability to No."

See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-list-form-configure-layout-body-not-working/m-p/3183590/highlight/true#M57614